# Can we use "depart" in the following sentence?

Tags: vocabulary, word-usage

Can we use "depart" in the following sentence?

> I departed from Jared, heading to the north as he went to the opposite direction.

I guess "depart" is mostly used for places. I wonder if it can be used for people, as well? Is it better to say "I separated from Jared"?

Comment: I took my leave from Jared.  Jared and I went our separate ways.  I left Jared, heading North and he South.

Answer (score 1):

I departed from Jared is technically correct, but it sure sounds wrong. When I read it I'm left questioning - not "who is Jared?", but "what is Jared?".

Separated sounds a lot better, or perhaps *I parted ways with Jared.*

Comment: Hmm, but "parted ways" means breaking up or becoming unfriendly. What I meant was just that we literally got far from each other.

Comment: Parted ways can just mean separate like that too, generally if it's for a long or indefinite amount of time. Whatever works best for you in the context :)